# typoscript renderObj image problem

Tags: typo3, typoscript

i dont figure out how i can render an image into my renderObj COA.
Here my code:

```
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
             10 = TEXT
             10.field = header
             10.parseFunc < lib.parseFunc_RTE
             10.wrap = <h2>|</h2>

             20 = TEXT
             20.field = bodytext
             20.parseFunc < lib.parseFunc_RTE

             30 = IMAGE
             ???
             30.parseFunc < lib.parseFunc_RTE
          }
```

As you can see i typed only three questionmarks as placeholder.
Please help me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on where you get the image from, here are some examples.

```
renderObj = COA
renderObj {
    # Static image
    10 = IMAGE
    10.file = fileadmin/user_upload/images/myPicture.jpg

    # From a database field
    20 = IMAGE
    20.file.import = uploads/pics/
    20.file.import {
        field = image
        listNum = 0
    }

}
```

There is no need to assign lib.parseFunc_RTE to the image, since that's only valid for RTE content.

See the official documentation, TSref, for more details on IMAGE ande imgResource.

IMAGE: http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/references/doc_core_tsref/4.4.0/view/1/7/#id2632631
imgResource: http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/references/doc_core_tsref/4.4.0/view/1/5/#id2619917